# Output two short clips with ffmpeg, one codec copy, one transcoded, starting at exactly the same time

Tags: ffmpeg

Using ffmpeg, I'd like to compare various transcoding options with the original video by making short clips and then getting a series of screenshots from them.

The problem is, I can't get clips with codec copy and transcodes that start at the exact same time.  I use something like

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -ss 2:00 -t 30 -c copy out.mp4
```

Even if I put the `-ss` before the input file, the video will start at a different time than the transcoded clips with the same seek time.

I tried using ffprobe to identify keyframes using this command:

```
ffprobe -loglevel verbose -select_streams v -show_entries \
   packet=pts_time,flags -of csv=print_section=1 \
   -read_intervals 01:50%+60 in.mp4
```

This nicely outputs a list of packets starting at 1:50 and going for 60 seconds, identifying keyframes with 'K'.  But if I change the seek times to a keyframe time, the codec copy and transcodes start at very different times.  If I seek to the packet time just before a keyframe, the two start pretty close, but still not the same.

Is there a way to do this?

EDIT: I actually got these results with an mkv input file.  I later tried an mp4, and seeking exactly to the keyframe (after finding them with ffprobe) works with this file, so the codec copy and transcoded clips start at the same frame.  (Although if I use `-avoid_negative_ts 1`, the resulting clip is one frame off.) Don't know why the mkv doesn't work.

Comment: Interesting - if I remux the mkv into an mp4 (codec copy), I can then get the clips to start at the same frame when copying and transcoding.  So this is the workaround.